# search aggregation result in main list

Tags: python, arrays, list, math

I want to check if the sum of the elements is in df=[200,107,25,30] by navigating through catch_list_7=[100,7], but when I enter 200, which is a larger value than the sum, my loop stays at 200 and does not continue. When I delete the 200 value, it works.

```
                is_match =False
                for i in catch_list_7 :
                    if is_match ==False:
                           for d in df: 
                            if abs(d-(i[0]+i[1]))<=0.2:
                                catch_list.append([i[0]+i[1],i[0],i[1]])
                                print("Total Gross", catch_list)
                                is_match = True
                                break
                            else: 
                                break
```

Comment: Not sure I understood what is your goal

Comment: if `catch_list_7=[100,7]` then `for i in catch_list_7` would make `i` an integer, then you index that like `i[0]` etc, which is not how integers work and should give you an `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` but as you are telling us the code runs then im guessing your paste above contains typos so please update it.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. If I add a value greater than 107 to the list, for does not return (like 200), but if I add a small value to the list, there is no problem.

Comment: the result should be catch_list=[107,100,7] but I can get it by deleting 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest encapsulating your code into functions; each logical block that does one precise thing should be one function.

This will make it much much easier for everyone to understand your code. By "everyone" I mean: StackOverflow users who read your questions; your colleagues; and more importantly, yourself now; and yourself in one month when you look at your own code with fresh eyes.

So, make a small function that takes a list of values, and a list of target sums, and checks if two values add to a target:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def catch_pairs_that_add_to_target(values, targets):
    targets_set = set(targets)
    caught_pairs = []
    for x,y in combinations(values, 2):
        if x + y in targets_set:
            caught_pairs.append((x,y))
    return caught_pairs

# TESTING
print( catch_pairs_that_add_to_target([100, 42, 7, 158], [200, 107, 25, 30]) )
# [(100, 7), (42, 158)]
```

If we're dealing with floats, we shouldn't test for exact equality; there is `math.isclose` for that case:

```py
from itertools import combinations
from math import isclose

def catch_pairs_that_add_to_target(values, targets):
    caught_pairs = []
    for x,y in combinations(values, 2):
        if any(isclose(x + y, z, abs_tol=0.2) for z in targets):
            caught_pairs.append((x,y))
    return caught_pairs

# TESTING
print( catch_pairs_that_add_to_target([100.1, 42.05, 7.07, 158.1], [200.0, 107.0, 25.0, 30.0]) )
# [(100.1, 7.07), (42.05, 158.1)]
```

Relevant documentation:

- [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to iterate on all pairs of values;
- [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) because `x + y in targets` is much faster if `targets` is a set than if it is a list;
- [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) to test for approximate equality of floating-points;
- [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check whether at least one element satisfies a predicate.

Comment: thank you for your help. Actually, I shared the relevant part of a work written as a method. my problem was solved thanks to you.